# Iterate over an array with subarrays

Tags: php, arrays

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["datos"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(652) "Fecha li­mite de entrega de la tarea TALLER INDIVIDUAL" [1]=> string(648) "Fecha limite de entrega de la tarea TALLER INDIVIDUAL" } } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["datos"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(800) "Sin contestar Test de Razonamiento Estadistico
Ayer, 08:00" } } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["datos"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(639) "Fecha limite de entrega de la tarea Taller Entropia y Negentropia (video)
jueves, 26 septiembre" } } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["datos"]=> array(0) { } } }
```

Hello, i have this array, and i'm trying to iterate over it, i try this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tareas[0]['datos']); $i++) { 
    var_dump($tareas[0]['datos'][$i]);
}
```

But i only get: ...

> string(639) "Fecha límite de entrega de la tarea Taller Entropia y
>   Negentropia (video) jueves, 26 septiembre" ....

It only iterate over the array `{ ["datos"]=> array(1)` but not in `{ ["datos"]=> array(2)`

Comment: you should use `foreach` and loop through the main `array(1)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is what you're wanting to do:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tareas); $i++) { 
    var_dump($tareas[$i]['datos'][0]);
}
```